# getting div tags to be centered in all computer sizes

Tags: html, css

I have a project where there are two div tags; one is on the left-hand side (links), and one is in the middle (menu). The one div tag on the left is working right, but the div tag in the center is the one causing me problems...

I have "links" centered well on my home computer, but when I get on my phone and view the site, because I have centered "menu" for the dimensions of my computer, it isn't centered to the small screen. It actually floats to the right.

I want the div tag in the middle (the one that says "menu") to be centered in the middle on ALL devices. How do I do that?

Here is the code:

CSS

```
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid red;
        border-radius: 25px;
    }

    body {
        background: darkgreen;
    }

    * {
        color: white;
    }

    #links {
        position: absolute;
        background: red;
        width: 100px;
        top: 70px;
        left: 10px; 
    }
    #menu {
        position: absolute;
        width: 50px;
        top: 70px;
        left: 830px;
    }
```

HTML

```
    <h1>Spanish Practice</h1>
    <div id = "links">
        <h3>Links:</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "http://www.studyspanish.com">Study Spanish</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id = "menu">
        <h3>words</h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand. None of your code does any centering of any kind aside from the h1.

Comment: @TreeTree - It only appeared to be centered to the OP because he positioned it specifically with respect to the screen he was on using position:absolute and left: 830px;

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a more permanent solution I would use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

it takes all horrible positioning troubles away.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/m39mzvak/1/)

with bootstrap all you need is this code below to achieve your desired results. No css needed.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-12'>
             <h1>Spanish Practice</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-12'>
            <div class='col-xs-4' id="links">
                 <h3>Links:</h3>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.studyspanish.com">Study Spanish</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-8' id="menu">
                 <h3>words</h3>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="https://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/m39mzvak/1/embedded/result/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Bootstrap? Seriously? For something this small and easy to fix? Seems a bit heavy-handed no?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the absolute positioning and left rules for #menu and just use:

```
#menu {
    margin:auto;
    width: 50px;
    top: 70px;
}
```

The auto margin will center the div on any screen.

```css
        h1 {

          text-align: center;

          border: 1px solid red;

          border-radius: 25px;

        }

        body {

          background: darkgreen;

        }

        * {

          color: white;

        }

        #links {

          position: absolute;

          background: red;

          width: 100px;

          top: 70px;

          left: 10px;

        }

        #menu {

          margin: auto;

          width: 50px;

          top: 70px;

        }
```

```html
 <h1>Spanish Practice</h1>

<div id="links">
  <h3>Links:</h3>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.studyspanish.com">Study Spanish</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="menu">
  <h3>words</h3>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tag `<li>` will make float left or right. if it is a single link in that menu `width: 50px;` you can set:

```
#menu a{
margin:0 auto;
}
```

if menu selector contains many tags `<li>` you can float it to the left or right and set it as above. other wise you can wrap it, example:

```
.wrapper{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:300px;  /* width is adjusted based on numbers of `<li>` menu*/
}

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id = "links">
            <h3>Links:</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href = "http://www.studyspanish.com">Study Spanish</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Notice that if you need it positioned center perfectly only if you use bootstrap. it is simple coding and gives you nice features to handle all the things you need.
Here's the [link](http://bootstrapzero.com/).

Answer (score -1):

you need media queries check out this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: What does this have to do with media queries?

Comment: he is talking about mobile devices that's why i suggested using media queries

Comment: You would need media queries, if you wanted different layouts for different device sizes. The OP wants the layout to be the same on all devices.